# Update multiple rows Mysql PHP taking long time and crashes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, updates

I want to update thousands of rows when the user click on a submit button, my function use another functions that calculates the field that I want to update.
My problem is when I try to update a few rows like 5 or 10 it works fine but when I have like 20 rows or more, it takes a long time to execute the code or sometimes, it displays a lot of errors that I don't have.
So can anyone help me please!

My code:

```
//----database connection
/* DATABASE CONFIGURATION */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', '8090');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'db_qvt');

function getDB(){
    $dbhost=DB_SERVER;
    $dbport=DB_PORT;
    $dbuser=DB_USERNAME;
    $dbpass=DB_PASSWORD;
    $dbname=DB_DATABASE;
    // Check connection
    $dbConnection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    mysqli_set_charset($dbConnection, "utf8");
     return $dbConnection;
}

//------------ update user final score--------------//
function update_user_final_score($login, $pass_user, $final_score){

  $sql_update="update users_answers set score_final = '$final_score' where login = '$login' and pass_user = '$pass_user'";
  $res = mysqli_query(getDB(), $sql_update);
  return $res;
}

//------------ calculate all users final scores--------------//
function update_all_users_final_score($login){
  $users_client = get_users_answers($login);
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($users_client);$i++){
    update_user_final_score($users_client[$i]['login'], $users_client[$i]['pass_user'], calculate_user_final_score($users_client[$i]['login'], $users_client[$i]['pass_user']));
  }
}
//-- call the function
update_all_users_final_score($login);
```

Comment: what is the contents of getDB() function? add it to your question

Comment: @YourCommonSense check the question again, I added the getDB() function code

Comment: creating a connection for every query within the update process is not a good practise. depending on your server settings this might lead to a crash

Comment: @YourCommonSense you're right, what's your suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you share the error messages? What have you tried to debug the problem - it should not be too hard to check whether your PHP code consumes too much time or the database queries

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't have any error in my code, i found out that i have the calculation functions who cause the lazy update and the errors. They make multiple connections to database. So I figured out the solution on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are using a loop for iterating over clients. This means that for every client you run a separate SQL query.

I believe you should create an SQL statement like this:

```
UPDATE users_answers
SET score_final = (case when login = 'X' then '1'
                        when login = 'Y' then '2'
                        when login = 'Z' then '3'
end);
```

This way you only have to run one query which should be a lot faster than running multiple queries.

The easiest way to create a query with multiple cases is to iterate over the client array, and add the cases ['when login="whatever" then "calculated_score"'] to the SQL statement string then pass the SQL command string to your mysql server.

Comment: can you provide me an example of case statement in a for or foreach statement? please!

Comment: it could be tricky to create a prepared statement for this query. So I would suggest  a more generic solution

Answer (score 1):

I would say tha one of the problems here is getDB() function that most likely **creates a new connection to a database every time it's called** which is obviously would be slower than using a single connection.

Also, the problem could be caused by some specific mysql configuration option, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`.

Either way, the most robust and error-free method for the multiple inserts would be to use a **prepared statement** with all inserts wrapped in a **transaction**.

So the code would be

```
function update_user_final_score($db, $login, $pass_user, $final_score){

  $sql = "update users_answers set score_final=? where login=? and pass_user=?";
  $stmt = $b->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $pass_user, $final_score);
  $stmt->execute();
}

function update_all_users_final_score($db, $login){
  $users = get_users_answers($login);
  $db->begin_transaction();
  foreach($users as $client){
    $score = calculate_user_final_score($client['login'], $client['pass_user']);
    update_user_final_score($db, $client['login'], $client['pass_user'], $score);
  }
  $db->commit();
}
```

so it could be called like this

```
$db = getDB();
update_all_users_final_score($db, $login);
```

Regarding error messages you are getting, most likely it's due to wrong SQL syntax, and this issue would be resolved by the use of prepared statements as well.

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me the same result as my code. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Then I have an answer for you

Comment: It's not a duplicated question and it's not the same code as mine

Comment: Your answer did not work for me

Comment: please remove the duplicated flag because it's not the same problem

Comment: Regarding the generic topic on improving the SQL performance, everthing is answered already. Regardoing your particular case, given you need only whatever "login" for the calculations, I bet everything could be done in the SQL. So it could be like UPDATE score_final=some calculations where login in (login1, login2, etc). It order to get help with this query I suggest to ask another question under mysql tag, in which you must explain in detail the table structure, what is the nature of calculations and everything else needed for the answer

Comment: I don't have any error in my code, i found out that i have the calculation functions who cause the lazy update and the errors. They make multiple connections to database. So I figured out the solution on my own